Content overflows and scrolling create rounded corner issue
I'm trying to create cards layout. Here is my layout.
<div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "start", width: "100%", height: "auto", padding: "2rem", gap: "1rem", borderRadius: "2rem", backdropFilter: "blur(4rem)", background: "goldenrod", }}>
  <div className="text-3xl unselectable font-bold" style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row",alignItems: "center",width: "100%", height: "3rem", }}>
    <div style={{ width: "auto", height: "3rem", alignItems: "center", display: "flex" }}>
      <Meteor weight="fill" color="#f2f2f2" /> { /* Phosphor Icons */}
    </div>
    <div style={{ width: "0.5rem", height: "100%" }}></div>
    Technologies and Mastery
  </div>

  <div className="card-container-grid-2">
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
    <div className="card">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>

Using this styles,
.card-container-grid-2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(100% / 3), 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 12rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

The error looks like this.

Cards are rendered nicely. But the container has overflow on Y axis, and it breaks rounded corner on bottom left and bottom right. Tried to control the scrolling overflow, but the scrollbar is unscrollable and rounded corner still sharp. How can I fix this? Any suggestions?

Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, not just a snippet of CSS that lacks context.

As above. Please also specify on which axis the overflow issue is being observed.
